# Objective C private instance variables error

Tags: objective-c

I am just starting out with Objective C  trying out a sample program about fractions from the Programming in Objective C book:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

//---- @interface section ----

@interface Fraction: NSObject

-(void)   print;
-(void)   setNumerator: (int) n;
-(void)   setDenominator: (int) d;

@end

//---- @implementation section ----

@implementation Fraction
{
 int  numerator;
 int  denominator;
}
-(void) print
{
  NSLog (@"%i/%i", numerator, denominator);
}

-(void) setNumerator: (int) n
{
  numerator = n;
}

-(void) setDenominator: (int) d
{
  denominator = d;
}

@end
```

//---- program section ----

I keep getting the inconsistent instance variable specification error for the instane variables numerator and denominator.If I move the declarations to the @interface section, the error goes away but I want to know why I am getting this error? I am using Xcode 3.6.2 on Snow Leopard 10.6.8

Comment: Off: I don't get this whole StackOverflow editing policy. I did the same edits, even better than what @bbum did and it was rejected. Reviewers should take time to understand what they are doing and do it responsibly. I'd happyily flag the reviewer if I could!

Comment: @allprog if I can figure out how to dig up your edits and if I can accept them, I will.   The editing thing baffles me, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting an error because ivars needs to be declared in the interface.

By the way, you're using a veeeeery old version of xcode (probably too old to submit to the appstore), so you might want to look into getting xcode 4.6. There's also been many updates to the Objective-C language. In modern objective-c, there is no longer a need to manually declare ivars like this.

If you REALLY would like to keep ivars out of the header file, you can declare them in an empty category interface (also called a "class extension") like this, in the .m file:

```
@interface YourClass() {
  ivars here
}
@end
```

Comment: As I mentioned, there is no error if I move the variable declarations to the @interface section.Does this mean the issue is related to the old version of Xcode?

Comment: Yes, so what's the problem?

Comment: Does public and private mean anything to you?

Comment: Yes, but it's not really used in Objective-C.

Comment: Btw I updated the answer to guide you in the right direction if you want to keep implementation specific ivars out of the header file

Comment: Can u please provide specific answer to the example I posted?

Comment: The answer is to move the ivars into the interface.

Comment: Ok, I got it working and I will mark the answer, but I have to remove the curly braces, they also give errors.

Comment: @user1107888 if you remove the braces, they are no longer instance variables.

Answer (score 3):

Instance variables in `@implementation` blocks are only supported since Xcode 4.2 (LLVM compiler version 3.0). You must upgrade your development tools to take advantage of this feature.

The motivation for this language feature is to achieve better *information hiding* in your class structure. That means that clients of your interface (your .h file) may not need to be aware of the ivars the class is using, so they are "hidden" in the implementation file.

Another way to hide ivar is to include them in a *class extension* in your implementation (.m) file:

```
// Fraction.m

@interface Fraction () {
  int  numerator;
  int  denominator;
}

@end

@implementation Fraction
// ...
@end
```

But it also requires Xcode 4.2+ and a modern runtime environment.

For complete compatibility with old compilers, ivars can only be placed in the interface section of the .h file.

Comment: I didn't think the class extension was supported that far back, though. I'm going to dig into some docs as to when that was added to the language.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Now that you mention it, according to [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex), it seems to be a recent addition as well. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Class extensions were supported really far back, but you didn't use to be able to put instance variables in them (the older tools were written with fragile base classes in mind, so you needed to have the ivars visible to subclasses).